# Персонаж не появляется на нужном месте Unity 3D

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RespawnPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;
    public GameObject DeadUI;
    public GameObject HPText;

    public void Respawn()
    {
        Player.GetComponent<HPScript>().playerHP = 100;

        HPText.GetComponent<Text>().text = System.Convert.ToString(Player.GetComponent<HPScript>().playerHP) + " HP";

        Player.transform.position = new Vector3(860, 225, 650);

        Cursor.visible = false;

        DeadUI.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

вот код
Срабатывает все кроме Player.transform.position = new Vector3(860, 225, 650);

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 vector = new Vector3(860, 225, 650);
        Player.transform.position = vector;
```

может поможет, у меня всё робит